# libpq: get data type

Tags: c++, postgresql

I am coding a cpp project with the database "postgreSQL".

I created a table in my database its type is `character varying(40)`.

Now I need to `SELECT` these data `FROM` the table in my cpp project. I knew that I should use the library `libpq`, this is the interface of "postgreSQL" for c/cpp.

I have succeeded in selecting data from the table. Now I am considering if it's possible to get the data type of this table. For example, here I want to get `character varying(40)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **PQftype**.

As described here: http://www.idiap.ch/~formaz/doc/postgreSQL/libpq-chapter17861.htm

And just take a look here about decoding return values: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/da7021e0608040738l3b0880a1q5a76b838937f8c78@mail.gmail.com

You must also use **PQfsize** to get field size.